# etree parsing xml with escaped html inside

Tags: html, xml, elementtree

I've got an xml file with escaped html inside, the field looks like this:

`<title>Some records title with html &lt;i&gt; This should be inside escaped html &lt;/i&gt;, end of the title</title>`

I am finding that element fine:

```
el = titles.find("x:title", NS)
```

but when I do:

`el.text`

it returns the text with non-escaped tags:

`'Some records title with html <i> This should be inside escaped html </i>;, end of the title'`

Why is so? Do I have to escape the html tags separately again even though it is provided escaped? I would like to be able to provide the xml with both escaped and non-escaped html tags (to sometimes display it as a text and sometimes as formatted text). How to provide it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ElementTree function `_escape_attrib()` could be used:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

text = '''<title>Some records title with html &lt;i&gt; This should be inside escaped html &lt;/i&gt;, end of the title</title>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(text)

print(ET._escape_attrib(root.text))
```

This will output `Some records title with html &lt;i&gt; This should be inside escaped html &lt;/i&gt;, end of the title`.